# Go back to the requested URL in Spring security

Tags: grails, spring-security

In `Grails 2.5.1` application i'm using [Spring security core plugin 2.0-RC5](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core)  , i would like to return back to the requested URL, for instance  to access page `payOnline` you need to be logged in first so i redirect to the login page after the successful login i want to go to `payOnline`.

How this could be achieved?

Comment: What version of Grails are you using? What version of the plugin are you using? Is the original request a GET or POST?

Comment: Please add more explanation.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore edited the original question

Comment: @Sherif did you got it working ?

Answer (score 0):

> To access page payOnline you need to be logged in first so i redirect to the login page after the successful login i want to go to payOnline.

**1. Go to Requested page :**

*By default spring security stores the request url you want to access before you are redirected to the login page. After you logged in successfully you are then redirected to the page you wanted.*

E.g.

```
User trying to access `/payOnline`
If user is not logged in redirect user to `login` page
user successfully logged in redirect to `/payOnline`
```

**What you are asking is the default behavior of `spring security core plugin`.**

If its not working as expected then please check if you have `successHandler.alwaysUseDefault` config property present in your `config.groovy`. If yes then remove it.

**2 . Got to specific page always :**

*If you want to go to specific page always after login then you you can specify the controller action to which you want to go in `UrlMappings.groovy` pretty easily.*

Just specify the controller and action to which you want to got after login like below

Lets suppose `Provision` Controller and `payOnline` action.

```
"/"(controller: "provision", action: "payOnline")
```

This will redirect all the successful login users to `payOnline` page.

> Reference :
>   http://docs.grails.org/2.5.1/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings

Comment: i think what you mentioned will make that always after login will got to `payOnline` but i don't what that . what i need is if any page defined that user must be logged in first will redirect the user to the login page then **get him back to the page he was trying to access previously**

Comment: Updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: i checked the `config` and found it `false` `grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.alwaysUseDefault = false` , is there anything i need to check too ?

Comment: I don't think of any other parameter for that right now, Please try again by removing it. If works then good else hope for another solution from someone.

Comment: i removed it completely from the `config` but still the same result !!

Comment: any new ideas ?